# Using xtrabackup-v2 as SST method in MariaDB Galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera, backup, xtrabackup

I have configured mariadb galera cluster as docker swarm service using official docker [image](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb):
during cluster startup rsync (default SST method) works fine.
Wanted to change it to xtrabackup or xtrabackup-v2, so used the following configuration in my.cnf according to [docs](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/sst.html#id3):

```
[mysqld]
wsrep_sst_auth = <wsrep_sst_user>:<password>
wsrep_sst_method = xtrabackup-v2 (or xtrabackup)
datadir = /var/lib/mysql/

[client]
socket =/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

donor server starts fine, but getting the errors below during joiner server startup:

> 2018-05-07 13:08:26 139750451541760 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
>   2018-05-07 13:08:26 139750232831744 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.0.37' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '108'  '' '
>   WSREP_SST: [INFO] Logging all stderr of SST/Innobackupex to syslog (20180507 13:08:26.937)
>
> 2018-05-07 13:08:29 139750249850624 [Note] WSREP: (fdead878, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
>
> 2018-05-07 13:10:07 139750232831744 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read 'ready ' from: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.0.37' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '108'  ''
>           Read: '(null)'
>
> 2018-05-07 13:10:07 139750232831744 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.0.37' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '108'  '' : 32 (Broken pipe)
>
> 2018-05-07 13:10:07 139750451541760 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to prepare for 'xtrabackup-v2' SST. Unrecoverable.
>   2018-05-07 13:10:07 139750451541760 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit

Other wsrep values:

```
wsrep_on=ON 
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so 
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm:// (for first node to start, and virtual_ip of the first node on 2 other nodes)
```

How to configure xtrabackup as SST method in MariaDB correctly?

Comment: Exactly which version of MariaDB is this? There have been several bugs with the xtrabackup SST methods in the earlier 10.1 and 10.2 versions.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could post your other wsrep variables from your .cnf files (my.cnf, server.cnf, ...).

Comment: 10.2.13+maria~jessie, posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two scripts (or maybe just the last one, but you need both) `/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_common` and `/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2` are broken in 10.2.13, but you can get fixed versions from bug ticket [MDEV-15254](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15254).